# stackanswers.vim - View answers from Stack Overflow within Vim

Tags: app, questions, answers

## Introduction

stackanswers.vim is a Vim plugin that allows a user to ask a question, and receive answers from Stack Overflow right into Vim.

## Usage

You can ask the question by running `:StackAnswers <question goes here>`
For example, if you wanted to know what object oriented programming is, you would run `:StackAnswers what is object oriented programming`.

## Source Code

The code can be found [at the stackanswers.vim Github repository](https://github.com/james9909/stackanswers.vim) -- along with some more information.
Pull requests are always welcome!